# Add Notebook Author and Title in Jupyter Notebook Cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to make a Jupyter Notebook file that also **can be converted to PDF** for the report. I would like to add Title and Author field, so when it's converted to PDF, the author and title field will show like the usual LaTeX PDF metadata format (Author & Title centered). How can I write it on the cell (because I use online Jupyter Notebook instead of installed it in local machine)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Insert the text:

```
"title": "My Title!",
"authors": [
  { "name": "Author1" },
  { "name": "Author2" }
]
```

at the end of the metadata notebook.

Also, add a comma above where the text is added.
The configuration that you can see in the screenshot below worked for me:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add the notebook metadata with clicking on "Edit" => "Edit Notebook Metadata" and insert:

```
"title": "It's a woodpecker from space",
"authors": [
  { "name": "Jorge Gustavo Rocha"  },
  { "name": "Matilde Rocha" }
]
```

Have a look at https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/249 for the whole discussion.

Comment: It looks like, in the current version (4.0.4 for me), notebook metadata is now under "View" => "Property Inspector" => "Advanced Tools"

Comment: I think they have changed it again, and for the latest version, notebook metadata can be found here - "View"->"Right Sidebar"->"Show Notebook Tools"->"Advanced Tools"->"Notebook Metadata".

Answer (score 0):

I checked you can add Author & Title in Notebook.

Visit https://ipypublish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metadata_tags.html

Visit GIF version https://ipypublish.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/metadata_edit.gif